# HTML form with dropdown forms, sending it to database

Tags: html, forms, html-select

I'm tying to make a html form with a dropbox where you can choose a few options. However when I want to send this to the databse, something goes wrong. Namely that it doesn't send the variable in the name but uses the option as variable.

```
    <select name="name">
        <option value="op1">op1</option>
        <option value="op2">op2</option>
        <option value="op3">op3</option>
        <option value="op4">op4</option>
    </select>
```

So when submitting this, it doesn't send var name with value opX but just opX.

While in a normal form box this seems to work:

```
    <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="79"><br>
```

This sends var email with value = stuff that I typed in.

I am accessing with:

```
    $name = $_POST["name"];
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What you mean by 'it doesn't send var name with value opX but just opX.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably be accessing your HTML form from some server-side language like PHP or Java.

Here's a PHP example:

```
  $varName = $_POST['name']; // Would equal op1, op2, op3 or op4
```

Comment: I'm doing exactly that, and it tells me: `Unknown column 'op1' in 'field list'`

Comment: Hi - Thank you for two important pieces of information: 1) you're using PHP (and, it seems, you're using it correctly)   ... AND 2) you're using SQL.  *Unknown column 'op1' in 'field list'* is a SQL error; it means that you don't have an 'op1' column in your database :)  EXAMPLE: `"select * from my_table where name='" . $varName . "';"`

Answer (score 0):

create a `hidden` type and add it under the `</select>` but within the same form.like `<input type=""hidden" name"submit" value="submit">`....then check whether its set or not..like in php

```
if(isset($_GET/POST[submit])
{
       //access your form data here..like:
       $x=$_GET/POST[name]
}
```

this is how you can be assured about whether data is set or not

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save data coming from html form, you must use server-side language. ASP,ASP.NET,PHP etc. are server-side programming language. 
  If you will use PHP or ASP, you should use MySql as a database. If you will use ASP.NET ,you should use MSSQL as a database. If you will use ASP , you should use MS Access Database.
  Example for ASP:

```
<%
variable = Request.Form("name")
variable2 = Request.Form("email")
Set conn=CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
dbpath="Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("db\yourdb.mdb")& ";Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" 
Conn.Open dbpath
sql = "INSERT INTO yourtable_name (your_field1,yur_field2) VALUES (' "&variable&" ',' "&variable2&" ')"
Conn.execute sql
%>
```